# What is the most efficient way to have a iterator over the references of a given numeric range?

Tags: rust

One way of doing this is to create an array or vector (`[0, 1, 2, ..., n]` and then use the `iter()` method. However, it is not memory efficient at all.

I tried the following implementation:

```
pub struct StaticIxIter {
    max: usize,
    current: usize,
    next: usize,
}

impl StaticIxIter {
    pub fn new(max: usize) -> Self {
        StaticIxIter {
            max,
            current: 0,
            next: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for StaticIxIter {
    type Item = &usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.next >= self.max {
            return None;
        }
        self.current = self.next;
        self.next += 1;
        Some(&self.current)
    }
}

fn main() {
    for element in StaticIxIter::new(10) {
        println!("{}", element);
    }
}
```

It won't compile:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:18:17
   |
18 |     type Item = &usize;
   |                 ^ expected lifetime parameter
```

Comment: Sounds like an xy question, why do you need an iterator of references

Comment: You can create an iterator over consecutive numbers using the range syntax: `0..n` is an iterator yielding the numbers `0`, `1`, …, `n - 1`.  If you want references to these numbers, you first need to have an owner for them – what shoudl the references refer to otherwise?  However, I agree with the previous comment that it does not seem useful to yield references instead of integers.  (For what it's worth, here's an [example to show how to get an iterator over references](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=40d28da526e2754a142b31bb08444a16&version=stable) anyway.)

Comment: As already said, if you want a reference, you must have an owner. Your first thought is the only way to do this: first creating a collection, and then have a reference on each element. Can you please answer the question? Why do you need this? What issue are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

For iterating over a list of numbers, you might want to use Rust's [range iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html).

Take a look at this iterator example, where a range is used:

```rust
for element in 0..100 {
    println!("{}", element);
}
```

Changing this to `0..max` is also perfectly fine. Don't forget to wrap this range between brackets like `(0..100).map(...)`  if you want to use iterator functions on it.

About borrowing; for borrowing iterator items, you need to have an owner for them. I recommend to keep your implementation as simple as possible. Why don't you borrow iterator items after you iterated over it, like this?

```rust
for element in 0..100 {
    println!("{}", &element);
    //             ^- borrow here
}
```